# How can I display and save the input/result image?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code which I'm running using `Node.js`. In this code, a `histogram equalization` process has been made. How can I display and save both the original image and the result (histogram equalized) image?

```
var jsfeat = require('./build/jsfeat.js');
var im = require('imagemagick');
var cols = 0;
var rows = 0;
var image = im.identify('abc.jpg', function(err, features){
    if (!err){ 
    cols = features.width;
    rows = features.height;
}
});

var my_matrix = new jsfeat.matrix_t(cols, rows, jsfeat.U8_t | jsfeat.C4_t, data_buffer = undefined);
var equalization = new jsfeat.matrix_t(cols, rows, jsfeat.U8_t | jsfeat.C4_t);
var result = jsfeat.imgproc.equalize_histogram(my_matrix, equalization);
```

Thanks.